# how to get the ID from two different select statement on single query?

Tags: c#

i am having hard time running this code, i have two select statement on a single query with different "statement", all i want  is to insert it on a database just the "ID" only and here is the code,

```
           sqc.Open();
            cmd = sqc.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "Select DepID from UserDept where Department =@depe and Position =@posi union all Select SalaryID from Salaries where Gradenumber =@gn and StepNumber =@sn";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@depe", cmbDept.SelectedItem.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@posi", cmbPos.SelectedItem.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gn", cmbgrade.SelectedItem.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sn", cmbstep.SelectedItem.ToString());
            sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            foreach (DataRow rr in dt.Rows)
            {
                cmd = sqc.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "insert into UserInfo2 (AccountID,DeptID,SalaryGrade,DateEmp,DateHired) Values (@idd,@dep,@sal,@emp,@hired)";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idd", "crap");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dep", rr[0].ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sal", rr[1].ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp", dtpEmployed.Value.ToShortDateString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hired", dtpPromoted.Value.ToShortDateString());
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Information successfully saved!", "Information!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }

            sqc.Close();
```

what im try to do is that if column name DEPID the subitem must be dep232 and the SALARYID is sal 232

i try this code on INSERT statement

```
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dep", rr[0].ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sal", rr[0].ToString());
```

the output is column name DEPID it has subitem sal243, it should be on SALARYID only
and there is another data which is DEPID is dep243 but the salaryID has dep243 also.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? There is no link between the two tables. This way you'll end up messing up all the data in the third table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so you have 2 queries and they're giving you the dept ID and the salary grade.. if either one of these two queries **only returns one row** then you can get away with doing this:

```
        cmd.CommandText = @"select * from 
(
Select DepID 
from UserDept 
where Department =@depe and Position =@posi 
) a cross join 
(
Select SalaryID 
from Salaries 
where Gradenumber =@gn and StepNumber =@sn
) b";
```

The @ at the start of the string lets it run over multiple lines, handy for formatting and making an sql easier to read.

If both your queries return more than one row, do not do this. You'll have to inner join the two tables together. There isn't enough information in your question to be sure how to do that; the relationship between the tables is not apparent

There are good reasons to avoid using AddWithValue, but that's a blog post (you can search for it) rather tHan a one liner I can type here. Caution though; you basically call to string on all your combo selected items without really considering what is the type of data in the database. If in the database things like gradenumber is stored as a number, you should at least be calling addwithvalue and passing a value that is a number (i.e. Convert.ToInt32(combo.selecteditem) ) rather than a string ( your current .ToString()ing method)

Comment: it return two rows, but the Salary and Department ID from the first row has the same ID which is sal243,the second row it has the same item too(dep243) on both column(salary&dep)

what i really want to happen is to give me just one row, if its DEPID the item should be dep243 only and for the salaryID it should be sal243.

Comment: You're going to need to revise your query so that the number of rows you get is the number of rows you want. If you want one row with I'd and 243 is coming back twice it's because two rows match your where clause. Revise the where clause so only one row matches. Doing select * will help

Comment: yeah thats my problem ahaha. can you do it for me or give me a hint?

Comment: i solved it but i can't explain how does my code run 
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dep",ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString());
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sal", ds.Tables[0].Rows[1].ItemArray[0].ToString());

thanks for the union all